# Why is my np.arccos not working in my for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, trigonometry

I have a for loop with a formula whit gives the following error:

```
 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos
  test3[i] = np.arccos(temp.x[i])
```

If I perform the formula withouth the np.arccos, it works. Does anyone know why the np.arccos is preventing the formula to work?

This is my simplified for loop:

```
for i in range(1,len(temp)):
    test3[i] = np.arccos(temp.x[i])
```

**EDIT**

This is my df named temp:

```
                         time      x      y      z  bat
0     2022-05-16 12:22:58.719  0.276  0.101 -0.919  NaN
1     2022-05-16 12:23:23.719  0.264  0.085 -0.927  NaN
2     2022-05-16 12:23:48.719  0.276  0.105 -0.906  NaN
3     2022-05-16 12:24:13.719  0.260  0.101 -0.919  NaN
4     2022-05-16 12:24:38.719  0.272  0.105 -0.915  NaN
                      ...    ...    ...    ...  ...
96376 2022-06-13 09:39:38.719 -0.083 -0.014 -0.957  NaN
96377 2022-06-13 09:40:03.719 -0.087 -0.018 -0.949  NaN
96378 2022-06-13 09:40:28.719 -0.094 -0.018 -0.962  NaN
96379 2022-06-13 09:40:53.719 -0.083 -0.018 -0.944  NaN
96380 2022-06-13 09:41:18.719 -0.551  0.006 -0.940  NaN
```

**EDIT 2**

And to make test3 variable i used:

```
test3 = np.zeros(len(temp))
```

**EDIT 3**
Other numpy function do seem to work, like this one:

```
test3[i] = np.sqrt(temp.x[i-1]**2 + temp.y[i-1]**2 + temp.z[i-1]**2)
```

**EDIT 4**

Now I remove my above 1 and below -1 values I get a new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2131, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2140, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 632


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "C:\Users\untitled5.py", line 61, in <module>
        test3[i] = np.arccos(temp.x[i])# * temp.x[i-1] + temp.y[i] * temp.y[i-1] + temp.z[i] * temp.z[i-1])/(np.sqrt(temp.x[i]**2 + temp.y[i]**2 + temp.z[i]**2)) * np.sqrt(temp.x[i-1]**2 + temp.y[i-1]**2 + temp.z[i-1]**2)
    
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 942, in __getitem__
        return self._get_value(key)
    
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1051, in _get_value
        loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
        raise KeyError(key) from err
    
    KeyError: 632
```

Comment: What is *temp* ? The code shown doesn't seem to make sense (notwithstanding the potential for values passed to arches being out of range)

Comment: Temp is dataframe

Comment: You might want to enhance your question by showing how your DataFrame is being constructed

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added the dataframe

Comment: Suggest you check the value of temp.x[i] before passing to arccos to ensure that it's within -1 <= n <= 1

Comment: Yes this is what went wrong, I have some values above 1.0 , now I only need to know how to remove them, or maybe another solution

Comment: But now I got another error....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arccos` only takes values between -1 and 1 inclusive because otherwise you fall afoul of the range of the `cos` function.

[image: arccos] [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arcsine_Arccosine.svg)

If you check `temp.max(axis=1)` and `temp.min(axis=1)` it will give you a quick ballpark as to whether one of the values of any of the columns is outside of that range.

To get the exact rows (for `x` values, you can easily extend this to your `y` and `z` columns), you can use `temp.loc[(temp.x > 1) | (temp.x < -1)]` or `temp.query('x < -1 | x > 1')`.

As you have indicated in your answer, you have simply discarded these values, which is perfectly legitimate, but in other situations you could have used various imputation methods like taking the average between the values at the time step before and the time step after, provided that average falls in the range of `[-1, 1]`.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am using a acceleration sensor so sometime the vector does get above 1

Comment: @SimonDL So you'll likely either want to get rid of those rows completely or impute the values based on whatever system your discipline usually uses.

Comment: That are not many values, I guess  around 1 percent, so I can remove them. I am gonna find the code now how to do that. The best would be the change them from for example 1.2 to 1.0

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem thanks to everyone,

I removed the above 1 and -1 values, which is just a small part of my dataset:

```
temp = temp.loc[(temp["x"] <= 1)
                & (temp["x"] >= -1)
                [(temp["y"] <= 1)
                 & (temp["y"] >= -1)]
                [(temp["z"] <= 1)
                 & (temp["z"] >= -1)]]
```

**EDIT**

And because of removing some of the rows, the index becomes not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, but 1,5,10 etc. This will break the for loop. To restore this use reindex with drop - True:

```
temp = temp.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

Limited to the interval [-1,1]?